# IDLE doesn't recognise packages

Tags: python

I primarily use PyCharm but when I try to develop using IDLE it doesn't recognise any of my packages / folders. Even though they have a `__init__.py` file in them, any reason why and how can I fix it?

Thanks for any help, I can provide more information as and when it is needed.

Comment: Please provide more information. At the moment it's nigh-on unanswerable.

Comment: The only other information I am given is that IDLE crashes stating that the highest level module doesn't exist. For example "package net" doesn't exist and then it crashes.

Comment: Please add actual error messages and details. What's your current working directory? Where is your package relative to this directory? Are your packages on your PATH?

Comment: What interpreter are you using for the project? Is it a `virtualenv`? Is your package *installed* in that `venv`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have multiple versions of python, and Pycharm is using a different one than the version of IDLE you're using. It could also be that some packages like Pygame only work in 32 bit versions...